# PostgreSQL: Efficient way to get Average of records

Tags: postgresql, average

I have a table called `"ITEM_REVIEW"` with a column named `"score"`.

I know that I can get average of `score` by:

`SELECT AVG(score) FROM "ITEM_REVIEW" WHERE "item_id"=1`

Is this the right(and efficient) way to calculate average even when records are piled up? or is it better to fetch data and calculate average on my NodeJS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simplify it to

```
 SELECT AVG(ir.score) FROM "ITEM_REVIEW" ir
```

Yes it's massively more efficient to keep a million rows in the db on a fast hard disk, and calculate a single float that you pass over a network connection, than it is to transmit a million floats over a network connection into a shared server with more varied responsibilities and use some slow JavaScript to calculate the average

Databases are incredibly good at storing, collating, connecting and processing data; it's their sole purpose/entire reason for being. Teams of smart people spend all their time implementing and improving the performance of data processing features to ensure their db stays top of the pile. Leave your data in a database wherever possible, and drag the smallest number of bytes you can over slow network links (summarise and filter in the db always)

Comment: How is that a simplification?  It answers a different question.

Comment: See the edit history of the question -> the question I answered (he wrote `SELECT AVG(bbb.score) FROM (SELECT * FROM "ITEM_REVIEW") as bbb`) and the question as it now appears (he edited `SELECT AVG(score) FROM "ITEM_REVIEW" WHERE "item_id"=1`) are very different. I don't have a habit of quoting questions often, but perhaps I should. If you do find someone answering a question that doesn't seem to have been asked; check the timings (in this case click the "edited 9 hours ago" under the question) to see how the question may have appeared at the time an answer was posted

Comment: (Also bear in mind that even if an answer is posted after an edit it may have been drafted before. The mobile site is particularly poor at notifying changes, so the answer a person posts may have been based on how a question presented several minutes before the submission time of the answer, and the question may have been edited between the answerer reading it and the answer being submitted). All in I've no plans to change the majority of this answer as the essential info remains the same; don't drag a million rows out of a DB and then add them up in javascript,when the DB is perfectly capable

Answer (score 1):

If you really care, you should try it and see.  That way you get the correct answer for your versions, hardware, configuration, etc.  Pay special attention to memory usage, as NodeJS might store all the data in memory before it gets around to averaging it.

But in general trying to re-implement the database outside of the database is going to lose.  Not always, but in general.